# MFC Assertion fails after upgrading from VC++ 6 to MSVC 2005

Tags: c++, mfc

Is it normal to have to update assertions after upgrading the compiler from VC++ 6 to MSVC 2005? I have the following function which works without triggering the assertion in Visual Studio 6 but anything newer it fails.

```
void CMainFrame::OnUpdateGraphValue (CCmdUI* pCmdUI) {

    BOOL bMax;

    CMDIChildWnd *child = MDIGetActive (&bMax);
    if (child)
    {
        if (child->IsKindOf (RUNTIME_CLASS (CGaugeChildFrame)))
        {
            CGaugeView *pView = (CGaugeView *) child->GetActiveView ();
            if (pView->wndActive)
            {
                ASSERT (pView->IsKindOf (RUNTIME_CLASS (CGaugeView)));
                pCmdUI->Enable (TRUE);
                return;
            }
        }
        if (child->IsKindOf (RUNTIME_CLASS (CGarterChildFrame)))
        {
            CGarterView *pView = (CGarterView *) child->GetActiveView ();
            if (pView->wndGraphics)
            {
                ASSERT (pView->IsKindOf (RUNTIME_CLASS (CGarterView)));
                pCmdUI->Enable (TRUE);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

pCmdUI->Enable (FALSE); }
```

The failure occurs on line `ASSERT (pView->IsKindOf (RUNTIME_CLASS (CGaugeView)));` When I click print preview the type is not `CGaugeView` but `CPreviewView`.

Can someone please shed some light on this for me? Thanks

Comment: One of the differences between VC6 and VS2005 and up is a DEP (Data Execution Prevention) compatibility. VS2005 and up creates DEP compatible code, VC6 doesn't.
 
If you want to check that DEP compatibility might be the problem then use the editbin utility to remove DEP checking:
 
editbin /NXCOMPAT:NO YourApp.exe

Answer (score 2):

It's not valid to cast to a type before you have checked the type is compatible.

So you need to do:

```
   if(child->GetActiveView ()->IsKindOf(RUNTIME_CLASS(CGaugeView)))
   {
        CGaugeView *pView = (CGaugeView *) child->GetActiveView ();
```

As to why has this behaviour changed, I don't know. Maybe before you were ignoring the asserts? Maybe you didn't try a debug built?

Or maybe the print preview architecture has changed in version 7? Maybe there was no `pView->wndGraphics` in print preview mode in the previous version, so the code path never got triggered.

However since you aren't using the code path for anything maybe just dump it.